# Lotus View Sorting According to Numeric Values

Tags: lotus-notes

I created a categorized view which sorted according to "Text" Values. The first column has Text Value. But second Column has numeric values. there is also Total Column at the end. 
What i would like to do is to sort according to Numeric values(It can be Total Column)  from Biggest one to smallest one...[image: View Screen Shot..] is it possible to sort

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sort on the totals of a category.
You can only sort on data of documents itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the sorted column left of the categorized column. Therefor you add another column with the same value as the "Miktar" column as the first column of your view and make it sorted. After that you hide that column as it otherwise would look stupid.

Comment: I could not succeded. It looks stupit now :(( really. 
I put a sorted Column on the left of categorized Column. But the value of that column what should it be? and then the another column("Miktar")  
I have to add as the first column has to be categorized or just sorted..

Comment: See above: `with the same value as the Miktar column`. And I wrote „sorted“ not „categorized“, although this does not really matter...